# Imread causing fatal error on the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

This should be a really straightforward question. When I run the following code:

```
    #include "main.h"

    using namespace cv;
    int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
    {
        Mat image;
        image = imread("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg");
        namedWindow("k");
        imshow("k",image);
        waitKey(0);
    }
```

This [error](http://s24.postimg.org/5iifa36hx/Capture.jpg) shows up when I try to run the imread line. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong here?

Thank's in advace.

---

### Additional Info

This is being done in visual studio 2008 professional editions on a windows 7 32-bit machine.

I'm trying to debug the "Release" version.

This is the main.h file:

```
    #pragma once

    #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
    #endif

    #pragma warning( disable: 4996 )

    #include <cv.h>
    #include <highgui.hpp>
    #include <core.hpp>
```

My additional include directories (Configuration Properties -> C\C++ -> General) are:

- ...\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv2\highgui
- ...\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv2\
- ...\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv
- ...\OpenCV2.2\include

The (...) are merely for my privacy, the actual code contains the full path.

My "Additional Dependencies" (Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input) are:

- "...\OpenCV 2.2.0\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_core220.lib"
- "...\OpenCV 2.2.0\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_highgui220.lib"

Comment: Have you tried to "Press Break to debug"? And do it with the debug version, or add debug information to the release version.

Comment: did you include headers #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>, and #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>. Also return 0;

Comment: It might be a bug. Try update to OpenCV 2.4.x

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I didn't understood what you meant by "Press break to debug". Do you mean like, stepping through the program to find which line is given the problem? If so, I already did that, and found out that it was the line with the imread command.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı: Yes I did, but unfortunately I mistyped the contents of the main.h file. I have now corrected it, thank you.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev: I'm looking for alternatives other than that.

Comment: try image = imread("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg",1);

Comment: @baban: Same problem...